# sigc++ error during GTKmm cross-compilation

Tags: compilation, gtk, cross-compiling, gtkmm, libsigc++

I wrote simple GTKmm program from [here](http://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/2.24/sec-basics-simple-example.html.en) and try to cross-compile it for windows using mingw cross-compiler, but it fails. My output is [here](http://pastebin.com/13HQbVbU).

When I compile simple program using just GTK gtk.h header it works perfectly - compiles (using the same command) and run on Windows.

I am running Fedora LXDE spin and using GTKmm-2.4 (from win).

Everything else works fine - I can comile for UNIX GTK and GTKmm but for Win just GTK. I have my PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR set properly (one for UNIX and one for Win)

Thanks for any advice - I also tried to install new libsigc++ from Yum Extender but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Fedora includes a number of MinGW cross compiled libraries, including gtkmm 2.4 and libsigc++. I see you are using gtkmm installed in /home/michal/Dropbox/GTK/GTKmm-Devel/; have you tried using the system packages?

To install the binary packages: 'yum install mingw32-gtkmm24'

... and then to compile the [hello world sample](http://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/2.24/sec-helloworld.html.en), run:

```
i686-pc-mingw32-g++ helloworld.cc main.cc -o helloworld.exe `i686-pc-mingw32-pkg-config gtkmm-2.4 --cflags --libs`
```

Also, the [Fedora MinGW project](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/MinGW) has a mailing list and an IRC channel where people can help get you started.